# JSON string and .format() in python3

Tags: python, json, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to generate a JSON string using .format(). 
I tried the following:

```
TODO_JSON = '{"id": {0},"title": {1},"completed:" {2}}'
print(TODO_JSON.format(42, 'Some Task', False))
```

which raises

```
File "path/to/file", line 2, in <module>
    print(TODO_JSON.format(42, 'Some Task', False))
KeyError: '"id"'
```

Why is this error occurring ? Why is 'id' getting interpreted as a key and not as part of a string ?

Comment: This is fine for learning, but I'd use the `json` module for practical work as it'll escape things for you.

Comment: @NickT I was looking for a good reason to use the json module instead of a simple string – you provide a good one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{}` has special meaning in `str.format` (place holder and variable name), if you need literal `{}` with `format`, you can use `{{` and `}}`:

```
TODO_JSON = '{{"id": {0},"title": {1},"completed:" {2}}}'
print(TODO_JSON.format(42, 'Some Task', False))
# {"id": 42,"title": Some Task,"completed:" False}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%` formatting style.

```
TODO_JSON = '{"id": %i,"title": %s,"completed:" %s}'
print(TODO_JSON % (42, 'Some Task', False))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's trying to parse to outer `{}` that are part of the json formatting as something that should be formatted by `format`

But you should try the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module

```
import json
todo = {'id': 42, 'title': 'Some Task', 'completed': False}
TODO_JSON = json.dumps(todo)
```

Comment: My data comes in as a tuple from the database, so it's quire simple to just pass it in the string. What is the benefit of creating a dict and parsing it ?